# How to enable sockets extension in php-fpm?

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I want to enable the "sockets" in PHP-fpm how can I do that?

## As in XAMPP:
file php.ini

```
 `extension=sockets`
```

I have docker where I have installed the Nginx server and PHP-fpm. Now I want to enable the sockets extension as I have in the XAMPP server as above in the quotes.

## Want to achieve:

I want to achieve a typical socket communication like Client and Server over the sockets.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please share more details, like the current setup of your environmeht. Also, how is this related to nginx?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Dockerfile you must enable extension - add this line:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `install-php-extensions` in order to install and enable the `sockets` PHP extension (as well as a ton of other PHP extensions):

```
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN install-php-extensions sockets
```

More details on https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer